# SQL Junction Query - How To Get Exact Match

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, junction-table

I would like the answer to this question to be DBMS agnostic, but if it is relevant I am using Access SQL.

Please keep note that this is a simplified version of what I am trying to do.

Now, consider I have the following three tables.

My main fruits table(tblFruits):

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦
║ fruitID ║ fruitName ║ 
╠═════════╬═══════════╬
║ 1       ║ Apple     ║ 
║ 2       ║ Orange    ║ 
║ 3       ║ Grapefruit║ 
╚═════════╩═══════════╩
```

A junction table to link many tags to 1 fruit(tblFruitTagJunc):

```
╔════════════════╦═════════╦═════════════╗
║ fruitTagJuncID ║ fruitID ║ tagID       ║
╠════════════════╬═════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1              ║ 1       ║ 1           ║
║ 2              ║ 1       ║ 2           ║
║ 3              ║ 1       ║ 4           ║
║ 4              ║ 1       ║ 5           ║
║ 5              ║ 2       ║ 3           ║
║ 6              ║ 3       ║ 3           ║
║ 7              ║ 3       ║ 6           ║
╚════════════════╩═════════╩═════════════╝
```

And finally a tag table to tag my fruits(tblTag):

```
 ╔═════════╦═══════════╗
 ║ tagID   ║  tag      ║
 ╠═════════╬═══════════╣
 ║ 1       ║ Tasty     ║
 ║ 2       ║ Red       ║
 ║ 3       ║ Orange    ║
 ║ 4       ║ Shiny     ║
 ║ 5       ║ Delicious ║
 ║ 6       ║ Awful     ║
 ╚═════════╩═══════════╝
```

<sub>Thanks to [This Blog Post](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for letting me be lazy)</sub>

This essentially says that:

1. Apples are (Red, Shiny, Tasty, Delicious)
2. Oranges are (Orange)
3. Grapefruits are (Orange, Awful)

Now say that I want to select those fruits that have the tag 'Orange' and no others.  With the data presented, that would be only the one with `fruitName = 'Orange'`.  I am currently doing this:

```
SELECT F.fruitName 
FROM tblFruits F
INNER JOIN tblFruitTagJunc AS FTJ on F.fruitID = FTJ.fruitID
INNER JOIN tbltag as T ON FTJ.tagID = T.tagID
WHERE T.tag in('Orange') 
GROUP BY F.fruitName
HAVING count(T.tag) = 1
```

This would return both Orange AND Grapfruit in the result, but I only wanted Orange.

The reason I am doing the SQL statement this way is that different types of fruits may have the same name but different tags OR different fruits may have all but one of the same tags.

EDIT:

[SQLFiddle as requested](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59339f/1/0).

Comment: Note that column `tblFruitTagJunc.fruitTagJuncID` does no good for you whatsoever.  You would be better off dropping it (and its associated index, supposing it's a PK).  Since you'll want a unique index on (fruitId, tagId) anyway, just make that the PK.

Comment: So when you say you want to select only Oranges, does that mean `fruitName = 'Orange'` or does it mean `fruitID = 2`?

Comment: `HAVING count(T.tag) = 1` gives you fruit with only one tag.. therefore the `where t.tag in ('Orange')` is not needed.  Your query fails because you are restricting to only those tags that are orange.. already excluding the awful tag (grapefruit are yummy)

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've read quite a few times that it is better to have standalone PK and not need it than not have it and need it later. Since most junction tables I have encountered haven't really been that large I always try to include it. Although I do see the benefits/cons of both ways.

Comment: Interesting. I think HAVING clause is conflicting with the WHERE and /or INNER JOIN clause. Could you provide sqlfiddle please?

Comment: @JohnBollinger It means fruitID = 2, but I do not know the ID without the tags.

Comment: @Elias, it is best to not have it and not need it.

Comment: If selecting only oranges means `fruitId = 2`, then why is that not among your filter criteria?

Comment: To reiterate. I do not know the ID and am only looking it up by the tag.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it doesnt mean `fruitId = 2` it means `tagId = 3`

Comment: @paqogomez, Evidently it does *not* mean (only) `tagId = 3`, else it would not be wrong for the query to return both 'Grapefuit' and 'Orange'.

Comment: @JohnBollinger What OP is asking for are all the fruit that have the tag `orange` (grapefruit and orange) but ONLY the `orange` tag.  No other tags.  That is how yummy grapefruit is excluded.

Comment: @Elias, Gordon's answer is correct.  Also note that if you simply removed your where clause from your original query as I noted above, you'd get the same result (for different reasons)

Comment: @JA I added, the SQL Fiddle you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you need conditional aggregation in the `having` clause rather than a `where` clause.  When you use `where`, you never see the other tags.

So:

```
SELECT F.fruitName 
FROM tblFruits as F INNER JOIN
     tblFruitTagJunc AS FTJ
     on F.fruitID = FTJ.fruitID INNER JOIN
     tbltag as T
     ON FTJ.tagID = T.tagID
GROUP BY F.fruitName
HAVING SUM(iif(t.tag in ('Orange'), 1, 0) > 0 AND
       COUNT(t.tag) = 1;
```

Note that the "right" way to express conditionality is using `CASE` rather than `IIF()`.  Also Access usually requires lots of ugly parentheses around joins, which I am also leaving out.

Comment: Is this expandable to multiple tags? E.G. If I had a `Round` tag and orange and grapefruit were both linked to it would the statement work with `iif(t.tag in ("Orange","Round")...`? Per my Sql Fiddle below, it does not? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74bd90/1

Comment: Nevermind, minor mistake on my part. I forgot to switch the count to 2. Thanks for the help.